# Binary Search Tree Implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I am working on an assignment in Haskell and had a question about the implementation of a binary search tree that I was given. The book I am using to learn Haskell uses the following implementation for a binary tree:

```hs
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

This definition makes a lot of sense to me as it shows that a tree is either an empty tree or an element that contains a value and two trees. However, the implementation of a binary search tree that I was given in my assignment is as followed:

```hs
data BT a b
  = Leaf
  | Branch (BT a b) a b (BT a b)
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

In this implementation does each branch represent a pair of nodes that either is made up of more branches or leaves? Also what advantages/disadvantages would this implementation have over the traditional one? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this definition a `BT` is either a `Leaf` (not containing any values), or a `Branch` that contains two such `BT` subtrees, and an `a` and a `b` value.

Comment: This is a [*B-tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), a specific binary tree.

Comment: It's a slightly odd definition, though. I would think `data BT a = Leaf | Branch (BT a) a a (BT a)` would be more likely.

Comment: Also, a B-Tree usually (necessarily?) allows `n+1` children for a node with `n` values.

Comment: I suspect that `a` is the search key and `b` is the actual data. That would suggest functions like `insert :: Ord a => a -> b -> BT a b -> BT a b` and `find :: Ord a => a -> BT a b -> Maybe b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @chepner has nailed it.  This is intended to be a binary tree that contains both keys (of type `a`) and values (of type `b`).

Think of it this way.  If you started with the definition:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

and wanted to store a key/value pair at each node, you could make type `a` into a pair.  The following isn't a legal Haskell `data` type because you can't use `(k,v)` on the left-hand side, but it illustrates what the valid type `Tree (k,v)` would look like:

```
data Tree (k,v) = EmptyTree | Node (k,v) (Tree (k,v)) (Tree (k,v))
```

You could make this a valid Haskell type definition by making `k` and `v` proper arguments to the type constructor `Tree`, i.e., replacing `Tree (k,v)` with `Tree k v` everywhere:

```
data Tree k v = EmptyTree | Node (k,v) (Tree k v) (Tree k v)
```

Now, as a general rule, if you have a data type with a constructor that includes a pair:

```
data SomeType a b = Pair1 (a,b)
```

it's more or less equivalent to:

```
data SomeOtherType a b = Pair2 a b
```

After all, you can write `Pair1 (2,"hello")` or `Pair2 2 "hello"`, and they both store the same data.

Given this, we can rewrite the definition of `Tree k v` as:

```
data Tree k v = EmptyTree | Node k v (Tree k v) (Tree k v)
```

Now, the four fields in the `Node` constructor don't *have* to be in that order; we could reorder them and still store exactly the same information, so let's move the "left branch" field to the front:

```
data Tree k v = EmptyTree | Node (Tree k v) k v (Tree k v)
```

Now this exactly matches the structure of your `BT` type:

```
data BT a b = Leaf | Branch (BT a b) a b (BT a b)
```